# androidStudio - my country code picker doesnt works

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, mobile-country-code

why error ? i tried everythig , doesnt want to sysnce

i tri , updating my computer  , i took it from here  https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject#how-to-add-to-your-project and still didnt work so if anyone know what to do ? [thats what keep showing me i did invalidate caches , i used "" instead of '' and still doesnt work  ]  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynoQ2.png)

Answer (score 0):

You code should be like this:

```
implementation("com.hbb20:ccp:X.Y.Z")
```